# Excel VBA: Selecting a Range with an arbitrary amount of Rows, but set columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this will be something simple, but I haven't been able to find anything. I have this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AM8:BA")) Is Nothing Then
```

And then I have the rest of my code with actions. I'm trying to have my macro trigger if any of the cells in that range are changed. I get a syntax error at the BA part. What I'm trying to do is have the range work for any arbitrary amount of rows after 8 in column AM-BA. Ex: BA50, BA1000, etc

I'm sure it's a simple mistake, but I can't find it anywhere. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AM8:BA" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing Then
```